# Auto-completion on localizable (NSLocalizedString)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, localization, autocomplete

Simple question:
Is there a way to put auto-completion "ON" for NSLocalizedString key?

It's boring to go in localized.strings, then in my app files, then go back again in localized etc...

Thanks :)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9895621/730701).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Lin. https://github.com/questbeat/Lin

It's a Xcode4 plugin showing completion for NSLocalizedString and localizedStringForKey:value:table:

[image: Example of Lin]