# How to keep Storyboard strings up to date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, storyboard, localizable.strings

I have the Storyboard, Base language and translated all the app into another language, so far it's working fine.

I would like to know, when I add new elements in the Storyboard that needs to be localized, how do you keep the strings file up to date.

I tried a suggestion, which is to switch this: [image: Strings] to Interface Builder Cocoa Storyboard and then back to Localizable Strings, however the results are not good, most of the translation is lost and switched back to the Base language.

Is there a handy tool to regenerate and merge the strings in Storyboard? I tried few scripts but they always ended up wiping everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to update a localized storyboard's strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094259/is-it-possible-to-update-a-localized-storyboards-strings)

Comment: I posted a clean solution to this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35398661/3451975

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified a skript that i've found [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895621/best-practice-using-nslocalizedstring) to be able to also handle the localized strings in storyboards.

The skript only adds new key-value pairs to the .strings file, but keeps the ones that you have already translated.

You can get it from my [github](https://github.com/iv-mexx/update_localization), for more details about my localization workflow read [my blogpost](http://innovaptor.com/blog/2013/02/07/a-localization-workflow-that-works-well-in-practice.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I assume my folder structure is a tad different. I'm using a workspace, then in the MyApp folder I have the folders Base.lproj, de.lproj and so on, each containing Main_iPhone.strings and Localizable.strings. When I run the script (--interface) it creates the two strings files in the root folder.

Comment: You can specify the output path with the -o option, i run update_localization.py one time for each localization


_tools/update_localization.py -i Zurvive/ -o Zurvive/en.lproj/ --ignore 3rdParty --interface_


_tools/update_localization.py -i Zurvive/ -o Zurvive/de.lproj/ --ignore 3rdParty --interface_