# What is the correct way to use NSLocalizedString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring

```
subjectLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Kind Information", @"Info Label");
```

or

```
message.text= NSLocalizedString(@"Something Message",nil);
```

which is the correct one and what is the difference between these 2 examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice using NSLocalizedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895621/best-practice-using-nslocalizedstring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is

```
 subjectLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Kind Information", @"Info Label");
```

[image]

Comment: see red icon it's a clarifying comment above the pair in the key-value strings file

Comment: can you tell me one small thing? Suppose I am using Japanese and Chinese language, and I am writing code in English then what will be sample example. I understood how to create and write localization file with key and value. I want to know how to write in Xcode like subjectLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Click Button", @"Action");  how to write ?

Comment: I'm suffering understanding what u want drag the label as IBoutlet and assign the localized string to it in viewDidLoad , if this what u mean

Comment: What I want is that, whatever the static names of labels and button are there that names are I want to make localizable.

Comment: you can't localize IBOutlets and function names , coding is in English it's separate from the fact that you want to localize the app to multiple languages